# Visual Studio 2017 Error Update OData Service Reference

Tags: c#, soap, visual-studio-2017, odata

I've created a new project in visual studio community to consume and use SOAP or OData service. I've installed [the visual studio marketplace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=laylaliu.ODataConnectedService) to use this services.

I've been able to consume both, but when I try to update the OData service (click rigth in the OData Service>Update OData Connected Service..), Visual Studio throw this error:

[image: OData update error]

When I update the SOAP Service it works fine. I've found some information about this error but nothing its working for me.

Comment: You probably have problem with authoization, look at me answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54438382/3041364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Navision OData service right?

I believe the metadata url is: `http://<baseurl>/DynamicsNAV110/OData/$metadata` (Remove the company part, since that is part of the OData resource).

You can check this url by just opening it in your browser and seeing of you get a metadata XML document as the response.

Comment: Its right. I've used your answer ant it's working fine to me. But I decided do this with Visual Studio 2015