# Consume OData Service from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, odata, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I've a issue consuming Dynamics Nav OData. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 (version 15.9.0), and I've installed the extension OData Connected Service (Official Microsoft Extension)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw0eO.png).

[image: Extension installed at Visual Studio]

This is my Odata structure:

> http://myWeb:8145/DynamicsNav90_Desa/OData

I've verified and the odata is returning [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzUHz.png) values correctly at opera browser.

[image: OData Respone]

So far, it's working fine.

The problem is when I go to the visual studio and I try to add a new connected service, It throws the next error [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cywK.png):

[image: Odata ERROR]

Image text:

> Connected Services
>   Cannot access
>   http://myWeb:8145/DynamicsNav90_Desa/OData/$metadata

I've checked the firewall and the port information and they are totally open to connect.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, but I am unable to see your screenshots (blocked by our firewall). Maybe you can add the actual text?

Comment: Hello @johey try to refresh, maybe I was editing the publish to add more information.

Comment: That won't help, the domain imgur.com is completely blocked by our firewall / proxy server. :-|

Comment: @johey I've added the text error

Comment: Thanks for that. The problem does not really ring a bell though. Maybe it is security related? You can check this issue on OData's Github: https://github.com/OData/lab/issues/56

Comment: Post full steps how to add & invoking OData in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue (I'm also working with Dynamics Nav ;) )

The problem is that OData Connected Service doesn't support authorization.

You need to save metadata file locally and point it when adding OData Service Reference.

1. Open http://myWeb:8145/DynamicsNav90_Desa/OData/$metadata in the browser and save it on disk
2. Use path to this file during adding service reference in Visual Studio:
   [image: List item]

For me it works perfectly.

Comment: Post full steps how to add & invoking OData in ASP.Net.

Comment: @MagentoNav take a look at this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/walkthrough--creating-and-interacting-with-a-page-web-service--odata-)